# Mongod at 100% CPU - Not sure how to diagnose?

Tags: python, performance, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I have a python (python & mongo newbie) application that runs via cron every hour to fetch data, clean it and insert into mongo. During execution, the application will query mongo to check for duplicates and insert if the document is new.

I noticed recently that mongod is at 100% cpu utilization ... and I'm not sure when/why this started happening.

I'm running on an EC2 micro instance with a dedicated EBS volume for mongo, which is at ~2.2GB in size.

I'm not really sure where to start diagnosing the issue. Here is output of stats() and systemStatus() on the system:

```
> db.myApp.stats()
{
"ns" : "myApp.myApp",
"count" : 138096,
"size" : 106576816,
"avgObjSize" : 771.7588923647318,
"storageSize" : 133079040,
"numExtents" : 13,
"nindexes" : 1,
"lastExtentSize" : 27090944,
"paddingFactor" : 1,
"flags" : 1,
"totalIndexSize" : 4496800,
"indexSizes" : {
    "_id_" : 4496800
},
"ok" : 1
}
> db.serverStatus()
{
"host" : "kar",
"version" : "2.0.4",
"process" : "mongod",
"uptime" : 4146089,
"uptimeEstimate" : 3583433,
"localTime" : ISODate("2013-04-07T21:18:05.466Z"),
"globalLock" : {
    "totalTime" : 4146088784941,
    "lockTime" : 1483742858,
    "ratio" : 0.0003578656741237909,
    "currentQueue" : {
        "total" : 0,
        "readers" : 0,
        "writers" : 0
    },
    "activeClients" : {
        "total" : 2,
        "readers" : 2,
        "writers" : 0
    }
},
"mem" : {
    "bits" : 64,
    "resident" : 139,
    "virtual" : 1087,
    "supported" : true,
    "mapped" : 208,
    "mappedWithJournal" : 416
},
"connections" : {
    "current" : 7,
    "available" : 812
},
"extra_info" : {
    "note" : "fields vary by platform",
    "heap_usage_bytes" : 359456,
    "page_faults" : 634
},
"indexCounters" : {
    "btree" : {
        "accesses" : 3431,
        "hits" : 3431,
        "misses" : 0,
        "resets" : 0,
        "missRatio" : 0
    }
},
"backgroundFlushing" : {
    "flushes" : 69092,
    "total_ms" : 448897,
    "average_ms" : 6.497090835407862,
    "last_ms" : 0,
    "last_finished" : ISODate("2013-04-07T21:17:15.620Z")
},
"cursors" : {
    "totalOpen" : 0,
    "clientCursors_size" : 0,
    "timedOut" : 1
},
"network" : {
    "bytesIn" : 297154435,
    "bytesOut" : 222773714,
    "numRequests" : 1721768
},
"opcounters" : {
    "insert" : 138004,
    "query" : 359,
    "update" : 0,
    "delete" : 0,
    "getmore" : 0,
    "command" : 1583416
},
"asserts" : {
    "regular" : 0,
    "warning" : 0,
    "msg" : 0,
    "user" : 0,
    "rollovers" : 0
},
"writeBacksQueued" : false,
"dur" : {
    "commits" : 9,
    "journaledMB" : 0,
    "writeToDataFilesMB" : 0,
    "compression" : 0,
    "commitsInWriteLock" : 0,
    "earlyCommits" : 0,
    "timeMs" : {
        "dt" : 3180,
        "prepLogBuffer" : 0,
        "writeToJournal" : 0,
        "writeToDataFiles" : 0,
        "remapPrivateView" : 0
    }
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

And top output:

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+ COMMAND
18477 mongodb   20   0 1087m 139m 122m R 99.9 23.7  10729:36 mongod
```

I'm curious how to go about debugging mongo to determine where/what/why this awful performance is happening.

UPDATE:

I learned I can use explain() to get details, though I'm not sure how to yet interpret the results

```
> db.myApp.find({'id':'320969221423124481'}).explain()
{
"cursor" : "BasicCursor",
"nscanned" : 138124,
"nscannedObjects" : 138124,
"n" : 0,
"millis" : 3949,
"nYields" : 0,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"isMultiKey" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"indexBounds" : {

}
}
```

UPDATE:

OK, I see now that the example query (which it executes a BUNCH of times) is taking near 4 seconds. I guess it is NOT using any index. I need to lookup how to add an index...doing that now.

UPDATE:

So I did the following

```
db.myApp.ensureIndex({'id':1})
```

And it fixed everything. heh.

Comment: You do that. Why aren't you using the atomatic `_id`? It always has an index.

Comment: These id's are returned from a web service. The id returned is always unique for the document, so I use it.

Comment: Add an index for this additional `id`. It will occupy only few MB of you resident memory. As you can see from the `explain()`, the whole disk is being scanned: `"cursor" : "BasicCursor"` and `"nscanned" : 138124` which is equal to the total number of documents in your collection. This will dramatically improve your performance

Comment: orid - Right, I figured that out and updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: you could set the record _id to the id being returned from the web service, there is no real reason to keep the standard _id

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See my OP thread, but the answer was a missing index needed to be added:

```
db.myApp.ensureIndex({'id':1})
```